# Multi Kerberos authentication in spark streaming

Tags: linux, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kerberos

I'm working on POC for multi-Kerberos authentication for Kafka. I tried **Kafka mirror-maker, replicator and apache spark streaming** but still not able to authenticate with multiple krb with keytab.

Below is the scenario we have.
we have two Kafka clusters with different realms.

***A-Kafka-cluster.com***   and   ***B-Kafka-cluster.***

I want to replicate one topic data from A-Kafka-cluster to B-Kafka-cluster with multi Kerberos authentication with keytab.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to have multiple keytabs to do this.  You can [setup trust between realms](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system-level_authentication_guide/using_trusts) and 1 principle can work with elements in the other realms.

> 11.5.1. A Trust Relationship A trust means that the users within one realm are trusted to access the resources in another domain as if they
> belonged to that realm. This is done by creating a shared key for a
> single principal that is held in common by both domains.

Ask you friendly administrator to help you out with this and you can soon move forward without having to use multiple principles.